# Node script to request JSON data from REST API server

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, json, gis

First of all, I want to precise I am new with JavaScript and in the Geospatial field. Recently, I had the need of downloading data from a REST online service:
https://map.sitr.regione.sicilia.it/gis/rest/services/catasto/cartografia_catastale/MapServer/4/query Since i have to send thousands of requests, i have found this tool that should solve my problem: *https://github.com/tannerjt/AGStoShapefile*

Unfortunately, the index.js script of this repository pass a query to the server which gives me the 502 error. Maybe because the Italian server only allow 1000 request per time.

There is a way, starting from the index.js script, to ask the data to the server in an iterative way?

The problem that stress the server is related to this piece of index.js script:

```
data.toString().split('\n').forEach(function (service) {
        var service = service.split('|');
        if(service[0].split('').length == 0) return;
        var baseUrl = getBaseUrl(service[0].trim());
        var reqQS = {
            where: '1=1',
            returnIdsOnly: true,
            f: 'json'
        };
        var userQS = getUrlVars(service[0].trim());
        // mix one obj with another
        var qs = mixin(userQS, reqQS);
        qs = queryString.stringify(qs);
        var url = decodeURIComponent(getBaseUrl(baseUrl) + '/query/?' + qs);

        var throttle = 0;
        if(service.length > 2) {
            throttle = +service[2];
        }

        rp({
            url : url,
            method : 'GET',
            json : true
        }).then((body) => {
            requestService(service[0].trim(), service[1].trim(), body.objectIds, throttle);
        }).catch((err) => {
          console.log(err);
        });
    })
```

I have tried many time to change the request by changing the query, but due to my lack of knowledge of the javascript and node topic, i have not find solutions.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a delay using setTimeOut to resolve the rate limiting issue. This will make API calls with delay and prevent from getting 502 error code. Here is how you can do this:
const rp = require('request-promise');
const queryString = require('querystring');

```
// Your existing code for reading services goes here

async function makeRequests(services) {
    for (const service of services) {
        const baseUrl = getBaseUrl(service[0].trim());
        const reqQS = {
            where: '1=1',
            returnIdsOnly: true,
            f: 'json'
        };
        const userQS = getUrlVars(service[0].trim());
        // mix one obj with another
        const qs = mixin(userQS, reqQS);
        const queryString = queryString.stringify(qs);
        const url = decodeURIComponent(getBaseUrl(baseUrl) + '/query/?' + queryString);

        const throttle = service.length > 2 ? +service[2] : 0;

        await makeRequestWithDelay(url, throttle);
    }
}

function makeRequestWithDelay(url, delay) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(async () => { // This will add the delay
            try {
                const body = await rp({
                    url: url,
                    method: 'GET',
                    json: true
                });
                requestService(service[0].trim(), service[1].trim(), body.objectIds, delay);
                resolve();
            } catch (err) {
                console.log(err);
                reject(err);
            }
        }, delay);
    });
}

// Call your function with the list of services
makeRequests(yourListOfServices);
```